# Errors encountered in param 0: Invalid value undefined supplied to : HardhatNetworkConfig

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, hardhat

My smart contract has to check balance of OpenSea OpenStore contract, so I need to be able to fork polygon mainnet. I want each test to start fresh with the same fork, so I'm invoking `hardhat_reset` in `beforeEach`. But I'm getting this incomprehensible error:

```
"before each" hook for "<very first 'it' under first 'describe'>":
     InvalidArgumentsError: Errors encountered in param 0: Invalid value undefined supplied to : HardhatNetworkConfig | undefined/forking: RpcForkConfig | undefined | undefined/jsonRpcUrl: string
```

My code looks like this (it's abridged, with ellipses filling in for standard boilerplate)

```
import ....
import * as helpers from "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers"

....

  async function deployContract(addr=myAddr) {
    await ethers.provider.send("hardhat_impersonateAccount", [addr])
    helpers.setBalance(addr, "0x100000000000000000000")
    const signer = await ethers.getSigner(addr)
    const cf = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContractName", signer)
    contract = await cf.deploy()
  }

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await network.provider.request({
      method: "hardhat_reset",
      params: [{
        forking: {
          url: "https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/" + apiKey,
          blockNumber: 31911877
        }
      }]
    })
    const wallets = waffle.provider.getWallets()
    wallet = wallets[0]
    await deployContract()
  })
```

Note that I don't get this issue if I move the `forking` param data to my `hardhat.config.ts` - in that case, the test executes fine except that because nothing is reset between tests, the actions done in the first test mess up the ones in later tests.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the `forking` params, replace `url` with `jsonRpcUrl`

I realized this after seeing https://stackoverflow.com/a/71811223/19350337